# Execute python files through code

Tags: python, pygame, exec, directory

I have a very simple, yet difficult question: I wasnt to execute a python script through python.

The idea is really simple, I want to build a sort of like interlinked "scripts". It would work just like links in HTML, I have a game with different screens (such as main game, settings, etc), and when the user clicks on a "link" (E.g. Play Game), it would execute the maingame.py script in the main game subfolder.

Now here comes the problem: I tried using `exec(open('somescript.py').read())` to open other scripts. However, the "python working folder" does not change (it doesn't change to the subfolder), and the imports in these scripts don't work because of this.

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a few options:

1. Use `subprocess.Popen` which seems to be heavily favoured here

   ```
   subprocess.Popen("python <path to .py file>")
   ```
2. Use `os.system` which is a slightly dated version of the above and is less preferable as you have less control with it

   ```
   os.system("python <path to .py file>")
   ```
3. I tend to like to import other functions, variables and whatnot straight into other scripts. In your `run.py` file import the other two:

   ```
   from run1 import *
   from run2 import *
   ```

This option gives you access to ANY function, class or variable in `run1` or `run2` from within `run.py`.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you! The Subprocess alternative seems to do exactly what I want! I will read more about the subprocess module as it seems to be extremely helpful.

This did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

ummm `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(script_name_to_run))`? ... why not just make the files follow some sort of framework where they all have a `run` method or something that does the script? then just import it like normal? this is probably much better in practice...

## file1.py

```
from file2 import run as run1
from file3 import run as run2
import random
[run1,run2][random.randint(0,1)]() # run one of them
```

## file2.py

```
def run():
    #do whatever
```

## file3.py

```
def run():
    #do something else
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying !

The thing is, I knew about the import option. However, I didn't want to use it because i've already used this alternative before, and as college project, I get more marks for using different methods.

Comment: using os.system would cost you points if I was the teacher :P